# Online Task Manager for website

Tags: php, html, database

Requesting some help on this task management system that i am making for class. I cant quite get it to work right. information is sometimes lost before it gets to the server and some of the last php code leeks thru to being seen on the site. can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong and help me to fix this? this code is supposed to allow you to send the task to a data base and the managing section relays the data from the database to the webpage. 
data base is set up as this 
3 Columns:
id - INT - 5 Length - Primary Key - AI.
description - VARCHAR - 255 Length.
active - BOOLEAN - 1 Length.

I am creating this on the hostica text editor that is within the site not an IDE if there are any discrepancy in the code

the website link is http://jtaylor84.net/taskmanager.php

I would like this code to work to take the information entered and relay it to the database and show in the managed tasks in order to have them up to be removed and show the tasks that have been entered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Online Task Manager</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div id="main">
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'Jhonny3_Task_Manager') or die(mysql_error());
if (isSet($_POST['createTask'])) {
if (isSet($_POST['desc']) && $_POST['desc'] != '') {
$desc = $_POST['desc'];
$q = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `tasks` VALUES ('', '$desc', '1')") or die(mysql_error());
if ($q) { echo 'Added task.';
}else
echo 'Failed to add task.';}}
if (isSet($_GET['removeTask']) && isSet($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
$q = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `tasks` SET `active`='0' WHERE `id`='$id'");
if ($q) { echo 'Task removed.';
}else
echo 'Failed to remove task.';}
?>
<h1>Add Task:</h1>

<form action='taskmanager.php' method='POST'>
Description of Task: <input type='text' name='desc'/>
<input type='submit' value='Create Task' name='createTask'/>
</form>


<h1>Manage Tasks:</h1>


<?php
$qu = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `active`='1'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($qu) > 0) {
```

after this section the code shows up on the web page and i am not sure why

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qu)) {
echo "";
echo $row['description'];
echo "<a href='taskmanager.php?removeTask&id=".$row['id']."'>Remove Task</a>";
}
}
?>

<footer id="foot01"></footer>

</div>

<script src="sitescript.js"></script>

</body>

</html> `
```

Comment: Your php is visible in your source code, so there is something wrong with your server php interpreter. You need to contact your host. see also [Why I can view my php source code online?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175714/why-i-can-view-my-php-source-code-online)

Comment: would that still be the case if it is only showing a portion of the php code and not all of the code?

Comment: it is showing all of the code. right click on your page, and click on 'view source code'. You will see all of your php code - screenshot from my browser http://i.stack.imgur.com/gbFFH.png. I should not be able to see any of that php code.

Comment: I just tried to change the PHP information thru my host and it basically deleted the page im going to try and fix it again.

Comment: @Piratica yes,problem might be your php server. i tried your code. it is working fine only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem might be your php server .your code working fine in my server .

[image]

Comment: I will contact them to see what the problem is. everything after the > sign is showing up on the site it regular view